# boot_completed action to register programmatically and not in manifest

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest, intentfilter, bootcompleted

I was trying to register a receiver programmatically for action`android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` ,
i.e 
Lets take i have reciever class named BootReceiver which extends `BroadCastReceiver` class.

So in one of my activity class i have written this code,

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter();
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED");
        intentFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.PACKAGE_REPLACED");

        BootReceiver receiver = new BootReceiver();
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(receiver, intentFilter);
```

I was trying to do both update of app as well boot_completed action to same broadcast receiver.

So what i tried is,
 I ran the activity with registering of above code and then restarted the device. I was not getting any callback to BootReceiver `onReceive()` method.

Is it possible to programmatically declare receiver for the boot_completed action or is it necessary to declare receiver in manifest file.

Actually my requirement is to programmatically declare it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May I ask why you dynamically declaring it would be a requirement?

Comment: Because I am creating a jar, so everything I wanted to put inside a method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I was trying to register a receiver programmatically for actionandroid.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED

By the time `registerReceiver()` is called, the boot will have long since happened. The only place to register for `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is in the manifest, as that is able to register interest in broadcasts even when you do not have a process running.

> Is it possible to programmatically declare receiver for the boot_completed action

No. You can request it, but it will never work.

> is it necessary to declare receiver in manifest file

If you want one to work, yes.

Comment: So you mean to say, even though i have run registerReceiver() and then do the boot, that register wont work.?

Comment: @NaveenKumar: Correct. `registerReceiver()` only works until either you call `unregisterReceiver()` or your process is terminated. Your process will be terminated as part of a reboot. If your "requirement" is to only respond to `BOOT_COMPLETED` in cases where you need it, use `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()` to toggle whether your `BOOT_COMPLETED` receiver is enabled or not. If it is disabled, the receiver will not get control on a reboot.